# ExtJS grid with summary row will not have "x-grid-item-over" on last row

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

Does anyone have this issue, and have a override fix?

- Having an grid/tree with summary row (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/31sk&view/editor)
- move mouse down (but don't hover yet on any rows)
- move mouse up from summary row to last row
- last row will not have x-grid-item-over

on 6.7 there is one more case that seems to be fixed in 7.3:

- if you move mouse from top to bottom when mouse gets out from grid, the last row has x-grid-item-over even the row is not "hover" anymore (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Summary.html)

I have this issue in extjs 6.7 but is not working even on 7.3

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/classic/Ext.grid.feature.Summary.html

[image]

[image]

move mouse bottom -> up
[image]

move mouse top -> bottom
[image]

Working Happy Flow
[image]